# Automatic translation of search queries using Lucene or similar technologies

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene

I am evaluating search technologies and one of my requirements is the ability to hit translated text also.

For example, there are text documents written in English and French. And lucene will index them.

If I am searching for the string "apple", it should search for both "apple" and "pomme"  and show documents with either.

Will any technologies provide automatic translation of token words ?

Or only way to do that is to translate it using Google API and then feed it to lucene for indexing?

Answer (score 0):

There are no automatic translations in Lucene/Solr/Elasticsearch, but they have a similar feature, called Synonyms. You can create a list of synonyms with Google Api to translate the terms in the search time, not the index time.

With this approach, you can search for "apple" and the search engine will see "apple" and "pomme" as synonyms, and you will get the result as expected.